# How to ignore files with @swc/cli?

Tags: javascript, typescript, swc-compiler

I am using `swc` to transpile my Typescript code on a side project and am struggling ignoring the tests files from the final output using the cli `--ignore` option.

lib versions:

```
 @swc/cli: ^0.1.57
 @swc/core: ^1.2.173
```

command:

```
swc ./src --out-dir dist --ignore **/*.test.ts
```

.swrc config

```
{
  "jsc": {
    "target": "es5",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "decorators": true,
      "dynamicImport": true
    }
  },
  "minify": true,
}
```

I still saw all tests files in my dist output folder. Note that using the exclude property in the .swcrc like this  `"exclude": [".*\\.spec|test\\.(j|t)s$", "mocks", "types"]` works, but how is the `--ignore` arg supposed to be used ?